# Incorrect results when using GROUP_CONCAT with a where clause condition

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have a table like this:

```
ID | GenEx   | CodeName | Desc
----------------------------
1  | Cipro   | Dolvo    | 
2  | Ludavil | Ymir     | 
3  | Cipro   | Alpha    |
```

My query is like this:

```
SELECT GenEx, GROUP_CONCAT(CodeName) AS Code 
FROM Drugs D 
WHERE `CodeName` IN ('Alpha')
GROUP BY GenEx;
```

The results I want are:

```
| Genex |    Code     |
+-------+-------------+
| Cipro | Dolvo,Alpha |
```

The results I get are:

```
| Genex |    Code     |
+-------+-------------+
| Cipro | Alpha,Alpha |
```

The `WHERE IN()` clause causes the `GROUP_CONCAT` to replace anything returned to match that restricting set. How can I get it to match the codes that are outside of that set, as long as `Alpha` is included?

Comment: b/c this is an example and I will be needed the where in more complicated queries

Comment: I understand. I deleted my comment, I misunderstood the first time I read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first write a subquery that gets which genex have the alpha code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT genex
FROM drugs
WHERE codeName = 'Alpha';
```

Then, you can use that as your `IN` clause so it only includes the genex that will have an Alpha in the group concat list:

```
SELECT genex, GROUP_CONCAT(code_name)
FROM drugs
WHERE genex IN (
   SELECT DISTINCT genex
   FROM drugs
   WHERE codeName = 'Alpha')
GROUP BY genex;
```

**EDIT**

A minor note regarding your subquery, you can still replace the `WHERE =`with `IN`, if you wanted to check for multiple codes down the line:

```
SELECT DISTINCT genex
FROM drugs
WHERE codeName IN ('Alpha');
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a4f28/4) example.

Comment: @Undermine2k Not a problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this if you don't want to use a subquery (for whatever reason):

```
SELECT GenEx, GROUP_CONCAT(CodeName) AS Code 
  FROM Drugs D 
 GROUP BY GenEx
HAVING 'Alpha' REGEXP GROUP_CONCAT(CodeName SEPARATOR '|');
```

or:

```
SELECT GenEx, GROUP_CONCAT(CodeName) AS Code 
  FROM Drugs D 
 GROUP BY GenEx
HAVING CONCAT(',',GROUP_CONCAT(CodeName),',') LIKE '%,Alpha,%';
```

But a subquery would almost certainly be more efficient than either of the two queries above.